# How to set delay with library cssanimation.io

Tags: css, css-animations

if someone know cssanimation.io, i have a little problem..
How can i set the animation-delay? I put it everywhere but the animation always starting when i reload the page rather than after 5s

Comment: http://codepen.io/cssanimation/pen/JRQyWp

Comment: this is the codepen of the original project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set animationdelay `delay = 5000;`

change delay in below code from `100`(default) to `5000`(5s)

```
window.onload = function () {
    splitText()
};
function splitText() {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('cssanimation');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var $this = a[i];
        var letter = $this.innerHTML;
        letter = letter.trim();
        var str = '';
        var delay = 5000;
        for (l = 0; l < letter.length; l++) {
            if (letter[l] != ' ') {
                str += '<span style="animation-delay:' + delay + 'ms; -moz-animation-delay:' + delay + 'ms; -webkit-animation-delay:' + delay + 'ms; ">' + letter[l] + '</span>';
                delay += 150;
            }
            else
                str += letter[l];
        }
        $this.innerHTML = str;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWvvBd)

Comment: Thank you it works..the only problem with this code is that by this way I cant set delay for each animation..